# Unexpected output in Java while adding of two Integers

Tags: java

I am new in java language, here is m not able to understand, why program returning -2 after adding two full range integers.

```
class Variables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2147483647;
        int b = 2147483647;
        long c = a + b;
        System.out.println( c );
    }
}
```

I am expacting 4294967294 value in my variable c, but why it returns -2
please explain me the reason behind this

Comment: You just reach Integer Overflow, the int are first summed as ints, then cast to long, but too late

Comment: Suggestion - learn how integers are represented in memory / binary. Then learn binary addition. Then you'll understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reach `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so you're going to `-2147483648`, then adding `Integer.MAX_VALUE` again will result in `-2`

To get `4294967294`, you need to cast one value as `long` before to do a `long` sum and not an `int` one

```
int a = 2147483647;
System.out.println(a + 1); //-2147483648

int b = 2147483647;
System.out.println(a + b); // -2

long c = a + (long) b; // or ((long) a) + b;
System.out.println(c); //4294967294
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of adding two `int`s is an `int`, which of course [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) when you add `a` and `b`. Only then is it promoted to a `long`.

You can get the result you expected by casting one of them to `long` before performing the addition:

```java
long c = ((long) a) + b;
```